# Sorting predicates

Tags: prolog

I have this predicates,

```
date(YYYY,MM,DD).
immigrant(IdPerson,Date).
```

and I want to know the `IdPerson` of the most recent immigrant. I saw the solution and I got this:

```
most_recent_immigrant(IDPerson):-
    findall(immigrants1(Data,IdPerson), immigrant(IDPerson,Data), ListOfImmigrants).
    sort(ListOfImmigrants,List),
    last(List, immigrants1(Data,IDPerson)).
```

So, if I understood well this exercise, we need to sort by date, however how can the sort alone do that? Or do I need something else to do the job?

Comment: Predicates cannot start with capital letters. Correct `Date/3` to `date/3` and `Immigrant/2` to `immigrant/2`.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Already changing.

Comment: Put pairs in `ListOfImmigrants` instead of `immigrants1/2` terms and see if [`keysort/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=keysort/2) helps you.

Comment: Please update the code in your problem statement to fix the issue with capitalized functors (you still have some in error in the code, such as `Immigrant(IDPerson, Data)`. An aside, if you use `setof/3` instead of `findall/3`, the result will already be sorted and you won't need a separate `sort/2`. Finally, sorting, in either case, is "smart" enough to know that, `a(X1,Y1)` is greater than `a(X2,Y2)` if `X1` > `X2`. So sorting a list of `immigrants1/2` will do what you want. Or, use `keysort/2` as @TudorBerariu indicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
most_recent_immigrant( Immigrant ) :-
  findall( immigrant(X,D) , immigrant(X,D) , L ) ,
  predsort( immigrant_compare , L , [Immigrant|_] ) .

immigrant_compare( = , immigrant(_,X) , immigrant(_,X) ) :- X = Y .
immigrant_compare( < , immigrant(_,X) , immigrant(_,Y) ) :- X > Y .
immigrant_compare( > , immigrant(_,X) , immigrant(_,Y) ) :- X < Y .
```

But, since you might have multiple immigrants on any given date, I'd probably do something like this:

```
most_recent_immigrants( Immigrants ) :-                   % to find the most recently arrived immigrant(s)...
  setof( D , immigrant(_,D) , Ds ) ,                      % get the [ordered] set of dates
  last( M , Ds ) ,                                        % the last item is the most recent dates
  findall( immigrant(N,D) , immigrant(N,D) , Immigrants ) % find all the immigrants on the specified date
  .
```